# Datagrid Command Binding to buttom, don't select row

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a command bound to a button on my datagrid (e.g. button shows for everyrow).
Basically the command is wired to an object which shows children of that row in a pop up window.

Problem is the customers wants it to display the chid data but not actually select that row in the datagrid.

Comment: so what action want the customer do - to show the childrows?

Comment: Basically the command pops up a new window (with the child details) this all works correctly. However they do not want that particular row to be selected afterwards. E.g. when you click the button it pops up the child window but does not select the row on the datagrid (weird behavior, but that is customers for you)!

Comment: îf i get it right all -  all your datagridrows have a button which open the child window? and the only problem is that the datagridrow is selected/selected after child window closed? if yes what behavior your customers want.

Comment: Yes the child window opens correctly. But we do not want that row to be selected when the child window closes. We want clicking the button to open the child window and show the details for the row of which the button belongs, but not to actually select the row in the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

you have some options:

- you can use a [style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046988/wpf-datagrid-disable-selected-row-styles-or-row-selecting)
- you can the [UnSelectAll() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765387/how-can-i-prevent-row-selection-in-the-wpf-toolkit-datagrid)

and if you google you will find some more

EDIT:

did you try to handle the PrevievMouseDown Event? you can set e.Handled=true if the user click on the button.

Comment: We don't want to unselect all, we want whatever was selected before that button was clicked to be unselected. Any ideas?

Comment: Just for some more clarity, basically if a user clicks on any other cell within the row we want to select that row. The user will also be able to multi-select rows. It is just this particular column, that if the user clicks a cell we want it to run the command that is bound but not to change anything regarding row selections.